# fgets conflict when reading some value and pressing enter

Tags: c, text, char, format, fgets

I have the following code snippet:

```
int val;
scanf("%d", &val);
char *c = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
fgets(c, MAX, stdin);
puts(c);
free(c);
```

that should basically read some integer named value and afterwards some text (MAX characters).

The thing is that when I run it and type 10, for example, (val = 10) and then press enter, it will "jump" over fgets. I think this happens because *a newline character makes fgets stop reading.*

How do I correct this program in order for it to let me enter val, press enter, and after that enter text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, add a [`getchar()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getchar) before `fgets()`, which will consume the last <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key press, stored in the input buffer.

```
int val;
scanf("%d", &val);
char *c = malloc(MAX * sizeof(char));
getchar();
fgets(c, MAX, stdin);
puts(c);
free(c);
```